# can we pass parameters to a copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a question regarding Copy constructors.

A constructor defined as below, do we call it a copy constructor or just an overloaded constructor ?

`A(const A& obj,int x, char y='A')`

Comment: If it's defined as in your question, then no it's not a copy-constructor, it's just a normal overloaded constructor. A copy constructor takes only one single argument, the object instance to copy from.

Comment: No, that constructor would not qualify as a copy constructor.

Comment: Copy constructor may have more than one parameter, if all of the additional parameters have default values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy constructors are defined thusly:

> **C++11 12.8/2**: A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments

In other words, it must be callable with a single argument - a reference to the object to be copied - but can have extra, optional, parameters.

Your example doesn't meet this requirement since it has two mandatory parameters. If the second parameter had a default value:

```
A(const A& obj, int x=42, char y='A')
```

then it would be a copy constructor.

Comment: Well "callable with a single argument" is not a defining criterion. It is defining for default constructor, but not for copy constructor. `T(...)` is a default constructor but `T(T const&, ...)` is not a copy constructor, as I see it. Disclaimer: influenza.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Indeed, "callable with a single argument" is necessary but not necessarily sufficient. The defining criteria are in the standard quote, not my plain(er) English summary.